# Android native crash

Tags: android, crash, native

We are not using any native code, as well our app doesn't have any native transitive dependency.

After recent release (we updated couple fo dependencies and add new) we started seeing crashes like this in Google Play:

```
native: pc 000000000006a548  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  native: pc 0000000000067cd8  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
  native: pc 0000000000024b78  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
  native: pc 000000000001f318  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
  native: pc 000000000043471c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+324)
  native: pc 0000000000137224  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
  native: pc 000000000030d988  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+2080)
  native: pc 000000000030df24  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+224)
  native: pc 000000000034ec64  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+616)
  native: pc 0000000000099094  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
  native: pc 0000000002a71ac4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat
```

I think it just Android itself but what might be the reason? Any assistance is appreciated.

Is there info about what this call means? Is it virtual machine some invocation?

```
_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list
```

Comment: https://demangler.com converts your method name to art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)

Comment: So basically it is call of some java method on some object that doesn't have to return something?

Comment: Right. Check this one out also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680487/jni-detected-error-in-application

Comment: Thanks, it is much better now but still not clear what and why

Comment: I've also been seeing the same crash in the play console logs. Seems to be limited only to Android 6.0 devices. @EugenMartynov any progress on the issue?

Comment: Do you use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2` library in your project? Here is a very similar issue that seems to be caused by a bug in this library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141733/android-6-0-native-tgkill-crash?rq=1

Comment: Hi @EugenMartynov, on what device(s) do you see these logs? And what Android version?

Comment: It is various devices and happens most on Android 6.0, and some amount on the Android 5.x

Comment: The problem seems to have occurred after I upgraded Google Play Services from 11.4.2 -> 11.8.0 for ads and location. Also in this timeframe firebase auth and database were added to the project.

Comment: @SergeyLebedev I have seen that too but the logs in the question seem like the same problem but the logs in the answer reference a different crash so that did not help unfortunately

Comment: These are the devices I have seen the crash happen on https://i.imgur.com/BbgC1xx.png. Seems to be a variety of cheaper devices with a common ARM Cortex-XXX CPU

Answer (score 4):

To start out I think the troublesome issue was finding the root cause as the Play Console does not provide the full stack trace and the stack trace also changes slightly depending on the device/android version. I have seen this `tgkill` native crash with many variations like the following but I've concluded that all of these crashes can be attributed to a [bug in the Support Library](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72614327)

`_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+440`
`_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+616`
`art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+580`
`_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+470`
`_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+560`

After much effort I was able to recreate this on a 6.0 Device on a screen in my application that contained an AppBarLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout + RecyclerView. The CollapsingToolbarLayout had the following scroll flags

`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"`

By scrolling all the way to the bottom and then quickly back to the top I was able to recreate the crash most of the time which yielded the following stacktrace

```
04-18 14:06:53.814 27077-27077/com.PACKAGE.NAME.debug A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.view.View.setElevation(float) on null object
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(java.lang.Object, long, float)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x740f26e8 self=0x558c24bf70
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=27077 nice=-6 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f8f6e8fc8
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 76543056125 12869243427 123563 ) utm=6830 stm=824 core=2 HZ=100
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0x7fef761000-0x7fef763000 stackSize=8MB
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 00000000004903d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+236)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 000000000045f598  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+220)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0000000000312970  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1000)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0000000000313228  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+116)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 000000000014501c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+144)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 000000000014557c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck17CheckMethodAndSigERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+1084)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 000000000015eaf8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_listNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+724)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 0000000000160d98  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+68)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 0000000000098fe0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 0000000000ad2cc4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_android_animation_PropertyValuesHolder_nCallFloatMethod__Ljava_lang_Object_2JF+168)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(Native method)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:37)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1296)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:981)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1384)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1427)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:759)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler$1.run(ValueAnimator.java:801)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]
```

The root cause of this seems to be related to a Support Library bug detailed [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64431012) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72614327)

**SOLUTION**

In my case all I had to do was remove the `snap` scroll flag and rollout that change. With that change I am not seeing any of these native crashes anymore in Play Console.

In other cases if you are using a StateListAnimator on the AppBarLayout you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928788/cant-call-void-android-view-view-setelevationfloat-on-null-object-in-lapism-s/40941206)

Comment: Fantastic answer. It helped us a lot reproducing and debugging the same problem. Can confirm that removing the "snap" flag is a workaround that worked for us as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was so sceptical about some dependency bug as a possible cause of the crash(es).

However, we've updated next in the latest release and crash disappears:

- Build tools 26.0.3 ->  27.0.3
- Android Gradle Plugin to 3.0.1 -> 3.1.0-rc01 (this also brings new data binding dependencies under the hood)
- DexGuard 8.0.23 -> 8.1.10
- Kotlin 1.2.21 -> 1.2.30
- RxJava 2.1.0 -> 2.1.10
- RxAndroid 2.0.1 -> 2.0.2
- Adjust 4.12.1 -> 4.12.2
- Multidex support 1.0.2 -> 1.0.3

Analyzing CHANGELOGS is quite hard and cumbersome. I spent a half of hour on it doesn't point to one obvious issue.

After reviewing over and over I think it might be dependency bug. But I can not say for sure since we also did quite many changes in these two weeks.