# Android 6.0 Native tgkill Crash

Tags: android, crash, native, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm having this native crash from today. It has been reported on only Android 6.0. with the stacktrace:

```
native: pc 0000000000049c34  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
native: pc 00000000000474cd  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+36)
native: pc 000000000001bbe3  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
native: pc 000000000001848d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
native: pc 00000000000164ec  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
native: pc 0000000000331875  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+228)
native: pc 00000000000f44db  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2226)
native: pc 000000000025a92f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1550)
native: pc 000000000025ad5b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+74)
native: pc 0000000000278577  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+470)
native: pc 0000000000062c9f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
```

Any advice on this will be helpful, because I am not able to understand this or reproduce this crash.

Answer (score 2):

I have Spent a few months banging my head against the wall and found out this error was caused by this google's library **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'**.

**Error back-trace as seen in play store console**

[image]

**From this graph error we can Clearly see that it is only occurring in android 6.0 devices**

[image]

All i did was to remove the library(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2) and give a 2% roll-out update to my users but again i had to put it back because i use it to server ads ;( . Therefore according to my research and live experimentation i found that, this is a bug in google play service library and i believe they will resolve it in no one know's when.

Comment: The library /system/lib/libc.so in which the crash occurs is present on Android devices - and not inside play-services-ads library.